# Converting a Macro created in Excel 2010 to Excel Mac 2011

Tags: excel, vba

The macro below runs in Excel 2010, but in Excel for Mac 2011 I get an error on the .Web commands. Is there a list of commands for both the Windows version and the Mac version?

The macro downloads financial data from stocks, which symbols listed in column H. The data of interest is in certain tables only, not all of them, so the command ".webtables". This data is copied to another section of the spreadsheet, the data is cleared and it continues until the list of symbols is exhausted.

Errors encountered:

At the following line, the macro stops and Excel closes the workbook:

```
.Name = "Yahoo analyst estimates"
```

Changing above line to:

```
.Name = False
```

allows the macro to continue, but none of the ".web" commands are interpreted.

So my key issue is to find the list of ".web" like commands for Excel for Mac 2011.

```
' Download_Yahoo_Metrics Macro
' Downloads Tables for Analyst Estimates, Analyst Opinion and Key Statistics
'
Dim ScrURL As String
    lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row 'delimits the last row
    fr = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, "C") 'delimits the first row
    For r = fr To lr
    Range("B5:F53").ClearContents 'clear previous
    ScrURL = "URL;http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ae?s=" & ActiveSheet.Cells(r, "H")
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=ScrURL, Destination:=Range("B5"))
    .Name = "Yahoo analyst estimates"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "8,11,14,17,20,23"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = True
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
    With ActiveSheet
      .Cells(r, "i") = .Range("C47")
      .Cells(r, "j") = .Range("D47")
      .Cells(r, "k") = .Range("F47")
      .Cells(r, "l") = .Range("C48")
      .Cells(r, "m") = .Range("C49")
      .Cells(r, "n") = .Range("D49")
      .Cells(r, "o") = .Range("F49")
    End With
  Next
    Range("A1").Select
  End Sub
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is nowhere that lists all the many differences between Mac and Windows VBA for Excel, especially as it varies by version too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be the connection and not the name of the QueryTable .
Tries to delete the connection and only then make the table .
Here you have a link that can help you: 
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-a-web-query-to-load-tables-in-excel-2011-for.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I had already seen that link.  The connection actually works (in Excel windows) and if I change .Name = "Yahoo analyst estimates" to .Name = False, the Macro continues but it stops again when it reaches the ".web" commands.  It appears that those are lines that need to be replaced with the right command for Excel for Mac.

Comment: Do you Already tried to make a macro to use QueryTables in Excel 2011 because it depends on versions . Try doing the same code with ListObject and see if work that way. 
I make some code in vba on my computer that other do not work QueryTables, just ListObject.

Comment: Not sure what ListObject command is but I've made macros that use Query tables and they worked.  I just can't figure out this one.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: ListObjet it's the same of QueryTables but don't have design, you can put after the make a table. The ListObject is compatible with all versions of Excel until now.